# Verification of solution for $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x\cdot \sin\{x\}}{x-1}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can you verify the solution to the following (very simple) problem
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x\cdot \sin\{x\}}{x-1},$$ where $\{\}$ is the fractional part function.

LHL = $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{(1-h)\cdot \sin(1-h)}{-h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{(1)\cdot \sin(1)}{-h}=-\infty$

RHL = $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{(1+h)\cdot \sin\{1+h\}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{(1)\cdot \sin(h)}{h}=1$

Since $LHL \neq RHL$ hence limit does not exist.

Is it correct to say that LHL does not exist? Or should I say LHL exists and is $-\infty$?

Comment: If the definition you’re using for the limit of a function (like the one for real functions) does not allow $-\infty$ to be a limit, then you should say that the left-hand limit doesn’t exist. If it does allow it (like the one for *extended* real functions), then you can say it is $-\infty$.

Comment: It looks good,  though the notation is a bit sloppy on the first it is valid.  You'd expect there to be no limit here since there's a jump discontinuity on the fractional function at 1

Comment: Your derivation gives the right answers, though you give the feeling that at places you are plugging $1$ for $1-h$ inside the limit, which is not rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot add comments, here's a short answer: It depends on how *you* define a limit. A standard definition of the limit of a function is—

A **real number** $L$ is the limit of a function $f$ at $a \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0, \, \exists \delta >0$ such that $0<|x-a|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

If perhaps, you don't understand whatever the bunch of symbols I've written above mean, that's fine. You don't need to. But the important part is that *I* have *defined* the limit $L$ to be a **real number** but $\infty$ is not a real number.

So it suffices to say that "Limit does not exist at $a$" to mean that "There exists no real number $L$ that satisfies those bunch of symbols". However, if you prefer to be more specific, you may add "... because $f(x)\to  ∞$ as $x \to a$" after it.